# Error: Cannot find module './lib/binding/napi-v3/argon2.node'

Tags: javascript, node.js

When installing bcrypt or argon2 using `npm install --ignore-scripts --omit=dev` I got the error

```
app-1    | node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
app-1    |   throw err;
app-1    |   ^
app-1    | 
app-1    | Error: Cannot find module './lib/binding/napi-v3/argon2.node'
app-1    | Require stack:
app-1    | - /app/node_modules/argon2/argon2.js
```

What can be, or how to solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is very simple. Just follow command below:

`npm install argon2 --ignore-script`

`npm install -g node-pre-gyp`

`node-pre-gyp rebuild -C ./node_modules/argon2`

Answer (score -1):

This solution worked for me, just uninstall argon2 and install it again:

```
npm uninstall argon2

npm i argon2
```